# JTRevealSideBar splitview adding a UISwipeGesture

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

Hi I am trying to add a swipe gesture to the splitview by using the JTRevealSideBar, similar to the facebook iphone application. I am unable to add a UIView on top of the SplitView area in order to add the swipe gesture. Your thoughts on this regard will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [PaperFold](https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFold-for-iOS.git). You can set numberOfFolds = 0 in MultiFoldView class
to disable folding effect